# SQL query to compare SUM of two columns from two different tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I am developing a website for a charity where amounts are pledged by individuals and recorded into a table. The individuals belong to a group. The payments received are recorded in another table however they are tagged to a group leader and not an individual. There can be multiple payments to reach the pledged amount.
I wanted an SQL query that would compare the amounts pledged by a group with the payments tagged to the group leader. My Tables are as follows:

*Donor Table*

| id | group_leader_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1001 | John |
| 1002 | 1001 | Steve |
| 1003 | 1001 | Richard |
| 1004 | 1004 | Paul |
| 1005 | 1004 | Stacy |
| 1006 | 1004 | Lucy |

*Pledged Table*

| id | amount | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 20 | 2023 |
| 1002 | 25 | 2023 |
| 1003 | 10 | 2023 |
| 1004 | 15 | 2023 |
| 1005 | 40 | 2023 |
| 1006 | 50 | 2023 |

*Payment Table*

| id | amount | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 10 | 2023 |
| 1001 | 10 | 2023 |
| 1001 | 20 | 2023 |
| 1001 | 15 | 2023 |
| 1004 | 35 | 2023 |
| 1004 | 35 | 2023 |
| 1004 | 35 | 2023 |

I have created two queries with sum but how can i compare them to check if the amount that has been pledged has been paid?

*query1*

```
SELECT Donor.Name Donor.id , SUM(Pledged.amount) 
FROM Donor , Pledged
WHERE Donor.id = Pledged.id
AND year = '2023'
GROUP BY group_leader_id
```

*query2*

```
SELECT Donor.id , SUM(Payment.amount) 
FROM Payment
WHERE year = '2023'
GROUP BY Donor.id
```

Comment: query1 seems to be missing a `,`, and after fixing that throws "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'fiddle.Donor.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by" (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/SeNAXM54, which uses the default settings for MySQL 8+)  (**and i did not even look at query2**)

Comment: What results do you want for the given input? Please read; [mre]

Answer (score 1):

You can JOIN the two queries like this:

```
SELECT query1.group_leader_id,
       Pledged,
       Payment,
       Pledged - Payment   as  Difference
FROM (
   -- query1 (corrected)
   SELECT group_leader_id , SUM(Pledged.amount) as Pledged
   FROM Donor 
   INNER JOIN Pledged ON Donor.id = Pledged.id
   WHERE  year = '2023'
   GROUP BY group_leader_id
  ) query1
INNER JOIN (
   -- query2 (corrected)
   SELECT id , SUM(Payment.amount) as Payment
   FROM Payment
   WHERE year = '2023'
   GROUP BY id
) query2  ON query1.group_leadeR_id = query2.id
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/KDBLPY1a)

You might need to change some small things, but that's because no desired output was given in your question ....

Comment: I'd use a LEFT join, just incase there haven't been any payments yet.

Comment: @MatBailie:  or a RIGHT JOIN to detect early payments ... 

Comment: Nah, I collect those in my superman account :)

Answer (score 0):

With this structure you can't assign a payment to an individual pledge.

This means that your aggregate output would presumably be the amount Pledged per group leader, vs the amount Paid per group leader.

That I need to presume that is one reason you've gotten such poor engagement for your question. Please ensure you include the expected results in your questions, as per the [mre] help page.

```
WITH
  pledge (
    donor_id,
    donor_name,
    year,
    pledge_amount
  )
AS
(
  SELECT
    d.group_leader_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN d.id = d.group_leader_id THEN d.Name END),
    p.year,
    SUM(p.amount)
  FROM
    donor     AS d
  INNER JOIN
    pledged   AS p
      ON d.id = p.id
  GROUP BY
    d.group_leader_id,
    p.year
),
  payment (
    donor_id,
    year,
    payment_amount
  )
AS
(
  SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.year,
    SUM(p.amount) 
  FROM
    payment  AS p
  GROUP BY
    p.id,
    p.year
)
SELECT
  pledge.*,
  COALESCE(payment.payment_amount, 0)
FROM
  pledge
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  payment
    ON  pledge.donor_id = payment.donor_id
    AND pledge.year     = payment.year
WHERE
  pledge.year = 2023
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/0u76nmpv

Answer (score 0):

```
with
  t as (
    select
      d.group_leader_id as gid,
      max(case 
            when d.id = d.group_leader_id then d.name
          end) as leader,
      sum(p.amount) as pledged
    from donor as d
    left join pledged as p
    on p.id = d.id
    group by d.group_leader_id
  )
select
  t.*,
  sum(p.amount) as paid
from t
left join payment as p
on p.id = t.gid
group by
  t.gid, t.leader, t.pledged;
```

Result:

```
+------+--------+----------+----------+
| gid  | leader | pledged  |   paid   |
+------+--------+----------+----------+
| 1001 | John   | 55.0000  | 55.0000  |
| 1004 | Paul   | 105.0000 | 105.0000 |
+------+--------+----------+----------+
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RrYnXmIe).

Answer (score -3):

Here is An Example:

```
SELECT
    Donor.group_leader_id AS group_leader,
    SUM(Pledged.amount) AS total_pledged,
    SUM(Payment.amount) AS total_paid,
    CASE WHEN SUM(Pledged.amount) = SUM(Payment.amount) THEN 'Paid in Full' ELSE 'Pending Payment' END AS payment_status
FROM Donor
JOIN Pledged ON Donor.id = Pledged.id
JOIN Payment ON Donor.group_leader_id = Payment.id
WHERE Donor.year = '2023' AND Payment.year = '2023'
GROUP BY Donor.group_leader_id
ORDER BY Donor.group_leader_id;
```

This query provides a clear comparison of pledged and paid amounts for each group, making it easy to track payment status and identify any outstanding balances.

Comment: `Unknown column 'Donor.year' in 'where clause'` ... (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/YsZX1xES )

Comment: If a donor has two rows in both Pledged and Payment, this will double count both tables. This should aggregate first, then join.

Comment: how do you aggregate first then join?

Comment: did you see above, i said example. not exact solution lol.